# eCommerce Mock App

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ecmascript-6, event-handling

This is a follow-up question to [eCommerce Mockup App in JS](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/227820/120114).

How do I implement the 'observe' pattern for the cart to regenerate html? So that, it will keep refresh its own. And any review on my coding style and code structure design?

```js
"use strict";

// Bugs
// 1. UI bug for cart item count. Non responsive.

// Initialization of data and page variables - start.
// For actual system, get data from database via API call either in JSON format.
const productList = [
    { id: 101, product: "Logitech Mouse", unitprice: 45.0, image: "LogitechMouse.jpg" },
    { id: 102, product: "Logitech Keyboard", unitprice: 50.0, image: "LogitechKeyboard.jpg" },
    { id: 103, product: "HP Mouse", unitprice: 35.0, image: "HpMouse.jpg" },
    { id: 104, product: "HP Keyboard", unitprice: 32.0, image: "HpKeyboard.jpg" },
    { id: 105, product: "Microsoft Mouse", unitprice: 43.0, image: "MsMouse.jpg" },
    { id: 106, product: "Microsoft Keyboard", unitprice: 39.0, image: "MsKeyboard.jpg" }
];

let productListFilter = []

var cart = [];
const $shoppingCartContainer = document.getElementById("shoppingCartContainer");
const $clearAll = document.getElementById("clearAll");
const $shoppingCart = document.getElementById("shoppingCart");
const $totalCartItems = document.getElementById("totalCartItems");
const $summary = document.getElementById("summary");
// Initialization of data and page variables - end.

// Functions - start -------------------------------------
const createCartHTMLElements = () => {
    if (cart.length  === 0) {
        return;
    }

    // Start our HTML
    let html = "<table><tbody>";

    cart.forEach(function (item) {
        html += `<tr class=productData><td class="productName">${item.product}</td>\
                <td class="productPrice">${item.unitprice.toFixed(2)}</td>\
                <td class="quantityProduct">\
                <i class="fa fa-plus plus-btn" data-id="${item.id}"></i>\
                <label class="quantity">${item.quantity}</label>\
                <i class="fa fa-minus minus-btn" data-id="${item.id}"></i>\
                </td>\
                <td class="total">${item.total.toFixed(2)}</td>\
                <td class="deleteProduct"><i class="fa fa-remove del" data-id="${
            item.id
            }"></i></td>\
                </tr>`;
    });

    // Finish the table:
    html += "</tbody></table>";

    // Return the table
    return html;
};

const updateQuantity = (operation, productId, tr) => {
    // Update the quantity in UI

    const $quantity = tr.find(".quantity");
    const n = $quantity.html();
    let i;
    switch (operation) {
        case "plus":
            i = parseInt(n) + 1;
            break;
        case "minus":
            i = parseInt(n) - 1;
            if (i < 0) i = 0; // prevent negative quantity

            if (i == 0) {
                // Duplicate code with delete function - start
                cart = cart.filter(function (el) {
                    return el.id != productId;
                });

                if (cart.length === 0) {
                    $clearAll.click();
                }
                updateCartCount();
                updateOrderSummary();
                // Duplicate code with delete function - end

                tr.closest("tr").remove(); // this is different
            }

            break;
    }

    $quantity.html(i);

    // Update the total price in UI
    const $price = tr.find(".productPrice");
    const price = parseFloat($price.html());
    const $total = tr.find(".total");
    const total = i * price;
    $total.html(total.toFixed(2));

    // Update the quantity and total in list object
    // Find index of specific object using findIndex method.
    const objIndex = cart.findIndex(obj => obj.id == productId);

    if (objIndex >= 0) {
        // Update object's name property.
        cart[objIndex].quantity = i;
        cart[objIndex].total = total;

        updateOrderSummary();
    }
};

const populateProducts = () => {
    debugger
    // Start our HTML
    let html = "";

    // Loop through members of the object
    productListFilter.forEach(function (item) {
        html += `<div class="column"><div class="card">\
                <div><img class=AddToCart data-id="${item.id}" 
                src="img/${item.image}" width=250 height=250></div>
                <h2>${item.product}</h2>
                <p class="price">RM ${item.unitprice.toFixed(2)}</p>
                <p><button class=AddToCart data-id="${item.id}">Add to Cart</button></p>\
                </div></div>`;
    });

    document.getElementById("productRow").innerHTML = html;

    createAddToCartEventListener();
};

const updateOrderSummary = () => {
    document.getElementById("totalItem").innerHTML = cart.length + " item";

    const subTotal = cart
        .reduce(function (acc, obj) {
            return acc + obj.total;
        }, 0)
        .toFixed(2);

    const shippingFee = 10;

    document.getElementById("subTotal").innerHTML = subTotal;
    document.getElementById("shippingFee").innerHTML = shippingFee.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = (
        parseInt(subTotal) + shippingFee
    ).toFixed(2);
};

const updateCartCount = () => {
    //let totalCount = 0;
    //cart.forEach(element => totalCount += element.quantity)

    $totalCartItems.innerHTML =
        cart.reduce((previous, element) => previous + element.quantity, 0);
};
// Functions - End  -------------------------------------

// Event listener - start -------------------------------------
const createAddToCartEventListener = () => {
    var addToCart = document.getElementsByClassName("AddToCart");

    //Array.prototype.forEach.call(addToCart, function (element) {
    [...addToCart].forEach(function (element) {
        element.addEventListener("click", function () {

            // Filter the selected "AddToCart" product from the ProductList list object.
            // And push the selected single product into shopping cart list object.
            productList.filter(prod => {
                if (prod.id == element.dataset.id) {

                    // Update the quantity in list object
                    // Find index of specific object using findIndex method.
                    let objIndex = cart.findIndex(
                        obj => obj.id == parseInt(element.dataset.id)
                    );
                    if (objIndex >= 0) {
                        // Old item found
                        cart[objIndex].quantity = cart[objIndex].quantity + 1;
                        cart[objIndex].total = cart[objIndex].quantity * prod.unitprice;
                    } else {
                        // For new item
                        prod.quantity = 1;
                        prod.total = prod.unitprice;
                        cart.push(prod);
                    }

                    $shoppingCart.innerHTML = createCartHTMLElements();

                    createDeleteEventListener();
                    createPlusButtonEventListener();
                    createMinusButtonEventListener();
                    $totalCartItems.style.display = "block";
                    $clearAll.style.display = "block";
                    $summary.style.display = "block";
                    updateCartCount();
                    updateOrderSummary();
                    return;
                }
            });
        });
    });
};

const createSearchProducts = () => {
    document.getElementById('btnSearch').addEventListener('click', function () {
        let $productName = document.getElementById('productName').value;
        console.log($productName)
        
        if ($productName.trim().length === 0) {
            productListFilter = productList;
        } else {
            productListFilter = productList.filter(product =>
                product.product.includes($productName)
            )
        }

        populateProducts();
    })
    //document.getElementById('productName').addEventListener('keyup', function (element) {
    //    productList = productList.filter(product => {
    //        console.log(product.product)
    //        console.log(element.key)
    //        product.product == element.key;
    //    })
    //    createAddToCartEventListener();
    //})
}

const createDeleteEventListener = () => {
    var del = document.getElementsByClassName("del");

    [...del].forEach(function (element) {
        element.addEventListener("click", function () {
            // Duplicate code with minus quantity function
            // When quantity is zero, it will delete that item
            cart = cart.filter(el => el.id != element.dataset.id);

            if (cart.length === 0) {
                $clearAll.click();
            }
            updateCartCount();
            updateOrderSummary();

            element.closest("tr").remove();
        });
    });
};

const createPlusButtonEventListener = () => {
    var plusBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("plus-btn");
    [...plusBtn].forEach(function (element) {
        element.addEventListener("click", function () {
            let productId = element.dataset.id;
            let $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
            updateQuantity("plus", productId, $tr);
        })
    })
}


const createMinusButtonEventListener = () => {
    var minusBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("minus-btn");
    [...minusBtn].forEach(function (element) {
        element.addEventListener("click", function () {
            let productId = element.dataset.id;
            let $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
            updateQuantity("minus", productId, $tr);
        })
    })
}

// $(document.body).on("click", ".plus-btn", function () {
//   let productId = $(this).attr("data-id");
//   let $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
//   updateQuantity("plus", productId, $tr);
// });

// $(document.body).on("click", ".minus-btn", function () {
//   let productId = $(this).attr("data-id");
//   let $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
//   updateQuantity("minus", productId, $tr);
// });

$clearAll.addEventListener("click", function () {
    $shoppingCart.innerHTML = "";
    $shoppingCartContainer.style.display = "none"
    cart.length = 0;
    $clearAll.style.display = "none";
    $summary.style.display = "none";
    updateOrderSummary();
    updateCartCount();
});

document.getElementById("cartIcon").addEventListener("click", function () {
    if ($shoppingCartContainer.style.display === "none") {

        if (cart.length === 0) {
            return
        }

        $shoppingCartContainer.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        $shoppingCartContainer.style.display = "none";
    }
});

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    $shoppingCartContainer.style.display = "none";
    window.setTimeout(function () { }, 1000); // prevent flickering
    productListFilter = productList;
    populateProducts();
    createSearchProducts();

    //createAddToCartEventListener();

    //updateCartCount();
});

// Event listener - end -------------------------------------
```

```css
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  width: 18em;
}

.price {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

img {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.card button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 12px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.card button:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.productContainer {
  margin: 15px;
}

.summaryDetails {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: right;
}

#productRow {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.column {
  flex: 1;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

@media (max-width: 1333px) {
  .column {
    flex-basis: 33.33%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1073px) {
  .column {
    flex-basis: 33.33%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 815px) {
  .column {
    flex-basis: 50%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 555px) {
  .column {
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 50px;
}

#left,
#right {
  width: 30%;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

#right {
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
}

#main {
  max-width: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

#shoppingCartContainer {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: lightyellow;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  margin-left: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.fa {
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.fa-shopping-cart {
  font-size: 36px;
}

.fa-remove {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: red;

}

#totalCartItems {
  margin: 0px 0px -2px auto;
  color: red;
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 10px;
  font-size: 1em;
  position: absolute;
}

.plus-btn img {
  margin-top: 2px;
}

tr.productData,
td.productName,
td.productPrice,
td.quantityProduct,
td.price,
td.deleteProduct {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="left">Login as Joe Doe, <a href="">Logout</a></div>
            <div id="right">
                <i id="cartIcon" class="fa fa-shopping-cart"> </i>
                <span id="totalCartItems"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search your product" id="productName" />
            <button id="btnSearch">Search</button>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="productContainer">
            <div id="productRow"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="shoppingCartContainer">
            <div id="shoppingCart"></div>
            <button id="clearAll">Clear Cart</button>

            <div id="summary">
                <hr>
                <h3>Order Summary</h3>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Subtotal (<span id="totalItem"></span>)</td>
                        <td class="summaryDetails"><span id="subTotal"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Shipping Fee</td>
                        <td class="summaryDetails"><span id="shippingFee"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Total</td>
                        <td class="summaryDetails"><span id="total"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <button>Proceed to checkout</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already gave many suggestions in [my review of your previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/228978/120114). I see that some of the advice has been incorporated - e.g. `"use strict"`, using the spread operator, etc. Yet it seems some of the advice hasn't been used (e.g. variables starting with `$`, using jQuery more, etc.) but I won't lose sleep about those.

I suggest avoiding use of `var` unless you have a good reason - e.g. you need a global variable.

In `createCartHTMLElements()` instead of appending to `html` each time, `map()` could be used to return the interpolated string for each row and then `Array.join()` could be used. Another option there is the HTML added in the `forEach()` callback could be stored in a [`<template>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) though [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template#Browser_compatibility) might be an issue.

In `updateQuantity()` instead of finding the index of the object to update, use `find()` to get a reference to the object and update that directly.

I see `updateOrderSummary()` has this variable:

> ```
> const shippingFee = 10;
> ```

If that is a true variable, perhaps it should be declared at the top of the code:

```
const SHPPING_FEE = 10;
```

I suggest ALL_CAPS because that is a common convention in many style guides to distinguish constants within code - like you did for `DELAY` (even though it was commented out) in your [blackjack code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/219638/120114).